# Calculate simple function with R

Tags: r

I have this function with R.

```
immediate.amput.EV <- function(Dead.prob=.010,Dead.cost=40000,Alive.prob=.0990,Alive.cost=50000,high=100,p.payoff=1) {
  return((Dead.prob * Dead.cost) + (Alive.prob * Alive.cost))
}     

immediate.amput.EV()

It's supposed to output : (0.010 * 40000) + (0.990 * 50000) = 400 + 49500 = 49900
Instead it gives me: 5350
```

Could you please tell me why?
Thanks..

Comment: it's like, i need to save the value and when i call the function i need that value to appear..

Comment: I think Dea means the numbers are different from what they are expected to be

Comment: Yeah. .0990 * 50000 = 4950 not 49500. So it's giving the right output

Comment: yes, the calculation doesn't seem like it's okay..

Comment: yes but in my r conosole i don't get that, i get 5350...

Comment: You could probably remove either Dead.prob or Alive.prob and auume they'll add up to 1

Comment: Saw your edit to .99 from .099 in the math; you need to change it in the function also and try rerunning it.

Comment: Well, it's obvious i didn't see i had a 0 in more there, i shouldn't be able to even post a question if i didn't knew the basics.. it was just an error my eye didn't catch

Comment: no biggie. It's just that 2 of us LOST reputation because of your sillyness. so you should at least accept an answer

Comment: @AwokeKnowing you should not expect answering a question like this to increase your reputation. At best, you're answering something anyone could answer, and at worst you're feeding the trolls.

Comment: @SeñorO I expected him to "delete" his silly question.  I mean first of all, SO is for finding bugs, however simple to "you".  There was no need for me to be downvoted for finding somebody's misplaced comma or semicolon or zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Brian Hannays says: Change the definition of `Alive.prob` to `1-Dead.prob`. A good programming habit is to try to avoid redundant (and then possibly conflicting) definitions...

```
function(Dead.prob=.010,Dead.cost=40000,Alive.prob=1-Dead.prob,Alive.cost=50000,high=100,p.payoff=1) {
  return((Dead.prob * Dead.cost) + (Alive.prob * Alive.cost))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your math is wrong.  In your comments, you added an extra 0

```
400 + 4950   NOT 49500


.01 *40000 =400 and .099*50000= 4950 and 400+4950 =5350
```

accept the answer or delete your question.

Comment: so then now it's giving the correct answer